# What is the fastest way to read a large tiff image in java?

Tags: java, image-processing, gis, tiff, jai

I currently use the **JAI library** to read the tiff image but it is very very slow large tiff images (I need to work with satellite images of size around 1GB).
I need to read the height of each point from the tiff image and then color it accordingly.

I am reading the image by creating a `PlanarImage` and iterating through every pixel by using the `image.getData().getPixel(x,y,arr)` method.

Suggest me a better way of implementing the solution.

Edit:
I found the error.I was creating a new raster of the image for every pixel by calling the image.getData() method in the for loop.Creating a raster just once and then using its getPixel() function in the loop solved my problem.

Comment: Are you using tiles (and are the TIFFs tiled)? I think processing smaller parts of the image at a time could potentially speed things up. Also, what do you mean by "read the height of each point from the tiff image and then color it accordingly"?

Comment: No I am not using tiles as of now.
I tried to read a tiff image of 20mb and it took hours to read the entire image.
The image is a satellite generated image where each pixel has a value that corresponds to the height of the place in the image.

Comment: It's currently unclear if it is the reading or the processing that is slow... Reading a TIFF is usually very straight-forward. What compression is the TIFF? Do you have a sample to share, or maybe some details about the image "layout"?

Comment: the image is a greyscale image,has just 1 band and the intensities stored range from 350 to 1300(all integer values).
the image is 3400x3100

Comment: 16 bits per sample? No compression? I don't see how just reading the image could take as much time as you describe, unless there's something very special about the image data.

Answer (score 1):

From the JavaDoc of `PlanarImage.getData()`:

> The returned Raster is semantically a copy.

This means that for every pixel of your image, you are creating a copy of the entire image in memory... This cannot give good performance.

Using `getTile(x, y)` or `getTiles()` should be faster.

Try:

```
PlanarImage image;

final int tilesX = image.getNumXTiles();
final int tilesY = image.getNumYTiles();

int[] arr = null;

for (int ty = image.getMinTileY(); ty < tilesY; ty++) {
    for (int tx = startX; tx < image.getMinTileX(); tx++) {
        Raster tile = image.getTile(tx, ty);
        final int w = tile.getWidth();
        final int h = tile.getHeight();

        for (int y = tile.getMinY(); y < h; y++) {
            for (int x = tile.getMinX(); x < w; x++) {
                arr = tile.getPixel(x, y, arr);
                // do stuff with arr
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
I was creating a new raster for every image.That took a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

A 1 GB compressed image is likely to be about 20 GB+ when loaded into memory.  The only way to handle this in Java is to load it with a very large heap space.

You are dealing with very large images and the simplest way to make this faster is to use a faster PC. I suggest an over clocked i7 3960X which you can get for a reasonable price http://www.cpubenchmark.net/high_end_cpus.html

Comment: It even takes very long time(in hours) for a image of size around 20MB... I am using an i5@2.3Ghz...

Comment: wow, that is a long time.  You definitely need a faster computer but it's not going to be more than 4x faster.

Comment: Are you sure it's taking this long just to load, or are you including the time it takes to process the file?

Comment: I iterated through all the pixels,read their values and stored them in a text file.
the file is 3400x3100 and it took half an hour to store 340x310 pixels(reading the every tenth pixel).

Comment: So it sounds like the reading the already loaded image is taking the time.  How effect is your writing of the text file.  This can be very slow if you are not careful.  I would try taking this out of your code to see how much difference it makes.

Comment: Just some comments: The largest single tile image you can read using normal Java2D classes, is ~2GB (signed 32 bit adressing). For comparison, I could read an 18000 x 18000 pixel RGB, 8 bpp, LZW compressed TIFF image (using my homegrown TIFF reader) in **about 25 seconds** on my i7@2.66GHz MBP.